# How to write higher-order function to provide control flow in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

EloquentJS Chapter 5 High-Order Functions at the example of functions provide new types of control flow.

Could someone please help me explain why the 2nd parameter of the unless function has to be

() => { console.log(n, "is even"); }

and not just

console.log(n, "is even")

```
function repeat(n, action) {
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        action(i);
    }
}

function unless(test, then) {
    if (!test) then();
}

repeat(3, n => {
    unless(n % 2 == 1, () => {
        console.log(n, "is even");
    });
});
// → 0 is even
// → 2 is even
```

When I tried passing only

console.log(n, "is even")

as the 2nd argument to the unless function, the result was not as expected, instead of only even numbers, all numbers were printed.

```
function unless(test, then) {
    if (!test) then;
}

repeat(3, n => {unless(n % 2 == 1, console.log(n, "is even"));});
// → 0 is even
// → 1 is even
// → 2 is even
```

Comment: The problem lies in the fact that you are providing console.log(n, "is even") as an argument to then. At that point this expression , namely:  < n "is event" > has already been evaluated and it prints the numbers in the console.
Furthermore when you evaluate if(!test) in unless function you return simply then, which is the evaluated console.log(n, "is even") argument. Console.log returns undefined and thus you just evaluate undefined (the value of then). Hope it helps !